# I have an invalid initialization of reference of type int& from expression of type in passing argument 1

Tags: c++, initialization

Im trying to lean structures and I think I am doing something wrong when I use the structure and trying to call it into a function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>  
using namespace std;


//Structure
struct Inventory
{

   int NumberPartsBin;
 };

 //Function Prototypes.

  void choiceMenu();
  void AddParts(int &);
  void RemoveParts(int &);

 int main()
 {
   char Election;
   int choice;

    Inventory Parts = {10};
    const int Valve_Choice = 1,
          Quit_Choice = 2;
```

I am trying to to resolve this problem with one item, but I will use arrays for             10 items.

```
   do {
   choiceMenu();
   cin>> choice; 
   if (choice >= Valve_Choice & choice <= Quit_Choice)
         {
                    switch(choice){
                      case Valve_Choice:
                           cout<<"Enter A for Add Parts or R to Romove Parts";
                           cin >> Election;
                           if (Election=='A')
                           {
                                  AddParts(Parts);// My problem is here
                                  }
                           if else (Election =='R'){
                                   RemoveParts(Parts);}
                           else{
                               cout << "Invalid Entry. Try Again";
                               cin >> Election; }

                           break;

                      case Quit_Choice:
                           cout<<"Program Ending";
                           return; 


                      else
                    {
                          cout<<"Enter a valid choice!!;
                          cin >> choice;
                          } 
                          }          
  }
  while (choice >= Valve_Choice & choice < Quit_Choice);

  system("pause");
   return 0;   


  // Bin Choice  
  void choiceMenu()
  {

   // We use ofstream to create and write on a text file.
     ofstream outputFile;
     outputFile.open("C:\\Users\\Alexander MR\\Desktop\\CompanyABCPayRoll.txt"); 
   // The headed of the document.

    outputFile << "                               Inventoy\n";
    outputFile << "                              = = = = = = = = \n";
    outputFile << " *Choose the part of your preference.\n";
    outputFile << " 1. valves = " << Parts.NumberPartsBin << endl;    
    outputFile << " 11. Choose 2 to quit the Program" << endl; 
    outputFile.close();
  }
```

I am not sure of my function either.
 my function to add parts
      void AddParts(int &Parts1)
      {
       int Enter1;

```
   Parts1.NumberPartsBin = Parts1.NumberPartsBin + Enter1; 

   }
```

My function to remove parts

```
   void RemoveParts(int &Parts2)
  {
     int Enter2;

     Parts2.NumberPartsBin = Parts2.NumberPartsBin - Enter2;

   }
```

Comment: Please format the code using the format tags `{}` present on the editor. From the function declaration `AddParts`, the argument is of type `int &` but you are passing `Inventory` type.

Comment: You function declaration and definition for AddParts don't agree (different argument - int/struct Inventory); you don't initialize Enter1 and Enter2 so they will have garbage values.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the question with only parts of the code formatted is quite hard. The first thing I saw was:

```
void RemoveParts( int &Parts2 ) {
    int Enter2;
    Parts2.NumberPartsBin = Parts2.NumberPartsBin - Enter2;
}
```

This makes no sense at all. If `Parts2` is an `int`, then you will never be able to say `Parts2.NumberPartsBin`. The second thing is `int Enter2;`. You never give it a value, but in the next line you want to subtract it from something‽

I'm guessing (at least with this function) that you are trying to do something like this:

```
void RemoveParts( Inventory& inventoryItem, int amountOfParts ) { // inventoryItem is passed by reference, amountOfParts is passed by value
    inventoryItem.NumberPartsBin = inventoryItem.NumberPartsBin - amountOfParts;
}
```

Looking at your code, I'm guessing you're quite new to all of this. I'm no guru, but please:

- Capitalize class/struct names and start variable names with a lowercase. ( like `parts` or `election`)
- If you want to change the value that comes into a function, pass it by reference, but if it is something like an `int` or a `char`, simply pass it by value.

p.s. it's `if`, `else if`, `else` and not `if else` which will otherwise be the next error in your code.

Comment: I fixed some part of it. its telling I should put a primary expression before void choiceMEnu()

Comment: @user3019164 If you want help with a specific error, please edit (and format) your post with all the code we need to see and the exact error and details you have. Besides that, I would advice you to start with an empty project and add code bit by bit. After every little thing you add you can then try to compile it. If it compiles, great! Add another thing. If it fails, then something is wrong with the last line(s) of code you added.

Comment: Inventory parts = {10};

Comment: Inventory parts = {10}cout << " 1. Valve. Currently Number of Valves = " << Bin.NumberPartsBin << endl

Comment: when I run the program. the number 10 does not appear as initial value.

Comment: Please edit your (original) post instead of (spamming) multiple comments. However, in your comment you have: `Inventory parts = {10}` but instead of doing `<< parts.NumberPartsBin` you are using some other variable called `Bin`.